# toFixed(3) -6.1e-15 returns -0.000, how can i ditch the minus?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

```
  it ("tests a positive zero", function() {
     expect((Math.sin(-1*Math.PI)*300).toFixed(3)).toEqual("0.000");
  });
```

But it fails, because it yields -0.000 (tested on chrome and safari). Removing the - with a regexp.replace is my last (and currently only solution) are there more?

Comment: Yay, floating point numbers and rounding issues.

Comment: What's `expect(...).toEqual(...)`?

Comment: @Rocket the expect().toEqual() is from Jasmine, a javascript unittest framework. I thought it was considered good practice at SO to include a unittest.

Comment: @dr jerry: Unit tests are good, I've just never heard of `Jasmine`.  I'm gonna look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.abs(number);//<<absolute value
```

Comment: This returns `0`, not `0.000`, just FYI.

Comment: @Rocket ...  so use `parseFloat()`.. or something to convert it. Also: `0 === 0.000`

Comment: @Kooilnc but that applied to Math.sin(Math.PI/-2) would not produce right results. I was hoping for an argument in toFixed or an alternative method where I can apply some number formatting as I can do in java or perl (or even excel)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `Math.abs((Math.sin(-1*Math.PI)*300)).toFixed(3)` work?

[edit based on comment] or:

`Number((Math.sin(-1*Math.PI)*300).toFixed(3)).toFixed(3);`

Comment: @Kooilnc -- see OP's comment on my answer (dont know why its there)

Answer (score 1):

Testing for "positive zero" is incorrect. If you want the number to be 0.000 to three dp, just check that the number is within (-0.0005, 0.0005). e.g.,

```
expect(Math.sin(-Math.PI) * 300).between(-0.0005, 0.0005);
```

(You may need to add a `between` method to your `expect`, if it doesn't already provide it under a different name.)

Comment: What's `expect(...).between(...)`?

Comment: @Rocket: It's a hypothetical function, possibly (hopefully) provided by the unit testing library the OP uses. It would throw an exception if the value is not in the given range.